# Can I display a field from a form in my form library view?

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-online

Once a user has submitted an Infopath form, can I have one of the fields in it (i.e. location 'London' or 'NYC') display in the library view of all the submitted forms?

If so, how do I do this?

Thanks,

Fin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the form options, you need to specify that your location in the form is a promoted field. Once it is promoted, it will display in the document library and you can sort/filter views based on that as needed.

http://localgovernmentsharepoint.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/infopath-property-promotion-accessing-your-infopath-fields-in-a-sharepoint-library/

Comment: Of course. I remember reading about that, now you mention it! I've just tested it and it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Great, if it answered your question, tick the little check box. Thanks for visiting sp.se!

Answer (score 1):

Re-run Publishing wizard and promote the fields you want to see

[image]

Comment: Yup! It's easy to forget to promote newly created field values. +1 for the screenshots, Gennady!  However, if you are publishing to "Administrator Approved" templates, the screenshots are going to be different.