# How can I add fields from an InfoPath form to a list?

Tags: list, document-library, infopath, column, document-template

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I display a field from a form in my form library view?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42883/can-i-display-a-field-from-a-form-in-my-form-library-view)

I have a document library that uses an InfoPath form as the standard template. How can I have data from the form, say "Name", be added to a column in the list when the user submits the form to the library?

So, in addition to the columns "Type", "Title", "Created", etc... I would like to add additional columns that display a field's data from the form.

Comment: Was already asked before [Can I display a field from a form in my form library view?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42883/can-i-display-a-field-from-a-form-in-my-form-library-view)

Answer (score 2):

While you are publishing to the Library there is a step (the step after you finish choosing the library you wish to publish to) in the wizard that you can use to map Fields from the form to those on the library.

Now I am not sure if you can craete those columns on the fly, so your better off creating those columns first and then try publishing and mapping the fields.

Here is a post for reference:

http://www.office-forums.com/show-infopath-form-fields-sharepoint-library-t100260.html