# Editing site columns then they disappear, where do I find them?

Tags: infopath, site-column, view

I have an InfoPath 2010 form that I have published to a SharePoint library. Users fill out this form and it goes through workflows from library to library and finally to a closed library. In that closed library there is a billing view, the column details were wrong so I went to edit them in Site Settings>Site Columns.

I selected the column and changed it from a single line of text to a number cause that what it was supposed to be however once I've done this the columns disappears from the list given.

How can I get the column back to edit it again?

Comment: It is not clear exactly where the column "disappears". What do you mean by "List given"? The Infopath data source? The list view in the site?

Comment: Under site actions, site settings, in site columns under galleries. There is a section for imported InfoPath columns, so I click on the name of the column I want to edit and then once I click okay that column is no longer under the list of imported InfoPath columns. List given would be all the imported columns from InfoPath.

Answer (score 0):

In order Infopath form template fields to appear in sharepoint views [those fields should be promoted during template publishing process / wizard](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/42891).